# How to populate in 3 collection in mongoDB with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have three collections such as `User`, `Program`, and `Agenda. Those models as follows.

**User Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type:String},
    email: {type:String}
},{timestamps:true
}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**Program Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const NoteSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type:String},
    timefrom: {type:Date},
    timeto: {type:Date},
    status: {type:String},
    venue: {type:String},
    timetype: {type:Number},
    userid:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref : 'User', required: true},
    logo :{type:String,default: 'programe'}
},{timestamps:true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Program', NoteSchema);
```

**Agenda Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const AgendaSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type:String},
    timefrom: {type:Date},
    timeto: {type:Date},
    status: {type:String},
    proorder: {type:String},
    proid:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref : 'Program', required: true}
},
{timestamps:true}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Agenda', AgendaSchema);
```

Now I only get agenda and program data only.

**Agenda Controller**

```
// Retrieve and return all agenda from the database.
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {

    Agenda.find()
    .populate('proid')
    //.populate('userid')

    .then(agendas => {
        res.send(agendas);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving agenda."
        });
    });
};
```

When I go to this URL and `GET` method I want to populate `agenda` document(done), related `program` document(done) and related `user` document(this I want)?

The wanted query as like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM users, programs, agendas
WHERE agendas.proid = programs.id AND programs.userid = users.id
```

Comment: what is your mongodb version?

Comment: MongoDB version is `4.0.0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation

```
Agenda.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Program.collection.name,
    "let": { "proid": "$proid" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$proid" ] } } },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": User.collection.name,
        "let": { "userid": "$userid" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$userid" ] } } },
        ],
        "as": "userid"
      }},
      { "$unwind": "$userid" }
    ],
    "as": "proid"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$proid" }
])
```

Or with populate

```
Agenda.find()
  .populate([{ path: 'proid', populate: { path: 'userid' }}])
```

Both will give you the same result

Comment: `populate` look more cleaner

Comment: @Hassaan But you cannot play with the data in `populate` and In the longer term of course `$lookup` is the better solution

Comment: Not success, It shows as earlier result (only agenda data and program data only, not showing the user data).

Comment: Nice Working Fine! Thanks @Anthony Winzlet

Comment: @ Anthony Winzlet, Can I get the list of all three collections from pragrams? here I want to get all details by `localhost:3000/programes/id=1` `GET` (Here we can easily get Programs and Users details such as documents by populate, but how to get agenda details, we should select all agenda documents by the given program `id`)?

Comment: you want agenda details in programs?

Comment: very nice saved my day

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.populate()` and `{ populate : { path : 'field' } }`.
Example:

```
Agenda.find().                    //Collection 1
        populate({path:'proid',   //Collection 2
        populate:{path:'userid'   //Collection 3
        }})
    .exec();
```

After the 4 collection, you need to identify the model, if it can't be wrong
Example:

```
    Agenda.find().                                    //Collection 1
        populate({path:'proid',                       //Collection 2
        populate:{path:'userid',                      //Collection 3
        populate:{path:'otherFiel', model: Collection //Collection 4 and more
        }}})
    .exec();
```

And to finish, if you want get only some fields of some Collection, you can use the propiertie `select` 
Example:

```
Agenda.find().                                    
        populate({path:'proid', select:'name status venue'                  
        populate:{path:'userid'               
        }})
    .exec();
```